# Mask on a rect during `OnGUI()` in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rect

I can only draw a texture to the image with `GUI.drawTexture(rect, pos)` during the `OnGUI` phase, because the textured pixels may be changed during the game.(if there are other ways other than making a shader to do this, please let me know).

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(imageRect, image, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);
                   // ^ imageRect is the red area in the demonstration.

}
```

And the image should also be movable & stretchable. And it also should be displayed in a restricted area.

As demonstrated bellow:
[image]
After annoying calculation, I could do the moving and stretch now, but the rect will always float above the screen, if I put the restriction math together, things will be a mess. So I want to know is there a sort of `Mask` available for the green line area during the `OnGUI()` phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html) component (it also uses a texture you can work on at runtime)?

Remember you need to call [`YOUR_TEXTURE.Apply();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) at the end of your computations. Also please note each RawImage used means a separate draw call.

`OnGUI()` should really only be used for debug and never for a final product as it is very poorly optimized (can be called more than 10 times per frames). Plus using Unity UI you can use a [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html) component to achieve what you are looking for.

*Hope this helps,*